# Scrapy with Celery not running on Docker container

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, celery, reactor

I code a Scrapy CrawlerProcess to run from script.
It also uses Celery+RabbitMQ for controlling the urls to be scrapped.

The `update.py` script sends the urls to RabbitMQ, and the Celery worker runs the Scrapy script.

When debugging on my IDE, it runs successfully.
However, when I try to run inside a Docker container, the script doesn't run.

I have already double checked `network` properties on `docker-compose.yaml` and everything looks correct.
I've been working and debbuging this for days, without any different result.

**update.py**

```py
...
for key in urls.keys():
        site_name = key
        links = urls[key]
        logger.info(f'Insert into queue: {key} | {len(links)} records')
        crawler_task.delay({'site_name': site_name, 'links': links})
...
```

**app.py** (Celery worker and setup)

```py
import logging
import os

from billiard.context import Process
from celery import Celery
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from twisted.internet import reactor

from enums import sites

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_broker():
    rabbitmq_user = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_USER')
    rabbitmq_password = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD')
    rabbitmq_host = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST')
    rabbitmq_port = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PORT')

    return f'amqp://{rabbitmq_user}:{rabbitmq_password}@{rabbitmq_host}:{rabbitmq_port}'


app = Celery('app', broker=get_broker())


class CrawlerScript(Process):
    def __init__(self, params):
        Process.__init__(self)
        settings = Settings()

        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'crawler.settings'
        settings_module_path = os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE']
        settings.setmodule(settings_module_path)

        links = params.get('links')
        site_name = params.get('site_name')

        site = sites.get(site_name)

        if site:
            self.spider = site.get('spider')
            spider_settings = site.get('settings')
            meta = site.get('meta')

            if spider_settings:
                settings.setdict(spider_settings)

            self.spider.urls = [{'listing_id': link.get('listing_id'), 'link': link.get('link')} for link in links]
            self.spider.meta = meta

            self.crawler = Crawler(self.spider, settings)
            self.crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)

        else:
            logger.error(f'No site found: {site_name}')

    def run(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(self.spider())
        reactor.run()


@app.task(soft_time_limit=30, time_limit=60)
def crawler_task(params):
    crawler = CrawlerScript(params)
    crawler.start()
    crawler.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**base.py** (Generic class to spiders)

```py
import scrapy

from crawler.items import Item
from enums.listing_status import ListingStatusEnum


class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    download_timeout = 30

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            print(f"START REQUESTS: {url.get('link')}") # This get printed while running on IDE
            yield scrapy.Request(url.get('link'),
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 errback=self.errback,
                                 cb_kwargs=dict(listing_id=url.get('listing_id')),
                                 meta=self.meta,
                                 dont_filter=True)

    def errback(self, failure):
        self.logger.error('ERROR CALLBACK', repr(failure))
        listing_id = failure.request.cb_kwargs['listing_id']
        status = ListingStatusEnum.URL_NOT_FOUND.value

        yield Item(listing_id=listing_id, name=None, price=None, status=status)
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.16-management-alpine
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "${RABBITMQ_USER}"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${RABBITMQ_PORT}:${RABBITMQ_PORT}"
      - "1${RABBITMQ_PORT}:1${RABBITMQ_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ./.docker/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1G
        reservations:
          memory: 512M

  crawler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: crawler
    command: bash -c "celery -A app worker --pool=threads --loglevel=INFO  --concurrency=1 -n worker@%n"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_USER: "${RABBITMQ_USER}"
      RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: "${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}"
      RABBITMQ_HOST: "${RABBITMQ_HOST}"
      RABBITMQ_PORT: "${RABBITMQ_PORT}"
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "4"
          memory: 3G
        reservations:
          memory: 512M
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "1G"
        max-file: "30"
```

When running on IDE, the script starts normally

**Output running on IDE**

```
[2022-04-07 08:53:54,330: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.crawler_task[e3b8401a-a6a7-4c1d-ac61-426cb8c1ccd0] received
[2022-04-07 08:54:04,732: INFO/MainProcess] Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'CRAWLER',
 'LOG_ENABLED': False,
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawler.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawler.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}
[2022-04-07 08:54:04,762: INFO/MainProcess] Telnet Password: 5e1278a7d809124a
[2022-04-07 08:54:04,794: INFO/MainProcess] Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
[2022-04-07 08:54:15,748: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
[2022-04-07 08:54:15,757: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
[2022-04-07 08:54:16,095: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Enabled item pipelines:
['crawler.pipelines.PricingCrawlerPipeline']
[2022-04-07 08:54:16,095: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Spider opened
[2022-04-07 08:54:16,996: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[2022-04-07 08:54:17,000: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023

**The script is running - START REQUESTS log from base.py**
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,831: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,872: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,878: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,884: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,889: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
[2022-04-07 08:54:18,894: WARNING/CrawlerScript-1] START REQUESTS: https://xxx
...
[2022-04-07 08:54:26,029: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Closing spider (finished)
[2022-04-07 08:54:26,037: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 6401,
 'downloader/request_count': 15,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 15,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1443579,
 'downloader/response_count': 15,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 14,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 9.036862,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 7, 11, 54, 26, 33066),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 7165556,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 14,
 'item_scraped_count': 14,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 14,
 'memusage/max': 96260096,
 'memusage/startup': 96260096,
 'response_received_count': 14,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 15,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 15,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 15,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 15,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 7, 11, 54, 16, 996204)}
[2022-04-07 08:54:26,038: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Spider closed (finished)
[2022-04-07 08:54:26,070: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.crawler_task[e3b8401a-a6a7-4c1d-ac61-426cb8c1ccd0] succeeded in 31.737013949023094s: None
```

When running on Docker, the script doesn't start

**Output running on Docker container**

```
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,000: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.crawler_task[2d05036b-ae92-488b-b7de-a6213905af48] received
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,009: INFO/MainProcess] Overridden settings:
crawler    | {'BOT_NAME': 'CRAWLER',
crawler    |  'LOG_ENABLED': False,
crawler    |  'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
crawler    |  'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawler.spiders',
crawler    |  'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawler.spiders'],
crawler    |  'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
crawler    |                'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,027: INFO/MainProcess] Telnet Password: f64b27b6d4457920
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,081: INFO/MainProcess] Enabled extensions:
crawler    | ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
crawler    |  'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
crawler    |  'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
crawler    |  'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,159: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Enabled downloader middlewares:
crawler    | ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
crawler    | [2022-04-07 12:18:33,164: INFO/CrawlerScript-1] Enabled spider middlewares:
crawler    | ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
crawler    |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
```

And nothing more happens.

I'm running on Python 3.8 with the following dependencies:

**requirements.txt**

```
scrapy==2.6.1
celery==5.2.3
billiard==3.6.4.0
```

Could be something related to `reactor` on Docker?
Any ideas on the reason why the script doesn't start on the container?

Comment: can you confirm by going inside the `crawler` container that it can connect to `rabbitmq` container?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ManishDash yes, it is connected to `rabbitmq` container. It shows `Task received` log.

Comment: Could you try to disable your `crawler.pipelines.PricingCrawlerPipeline` pipeline and runit?

Comment: Are you shure your environment is the same, in particular your environement variables you use?

Comment: you try it: docker run -it -v runtime-storage:/usr/src/app/runtime_storage -v results-storage:/usr/scr/app/results scrapyd-36

Comment: It might has to do something with your `start_requests` definition. Would you please try to pass a random url? like ```def start_requests(self):
   yield Request('https://stackoverflow.com', callback=parse_item)```